# Struts 2 JQuery Datepicker Issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, struts2, datepicker

I am using Struts 2 Jquery Date picker for selection of date.

Like below

```
 <sj:datepicker name="testDate" 
              parentTheme="simple"
              zindex="2006"
              timepicker="true"
              changeYear="true"
              displayFormat="dd/mm/yy"
              timepickerFormat="HH:mm:ss"
              timepickerShowSecond="true"
              duration="fast"
              readonly="true"   
          ></sj:datepicker>
```

If you can see the format I mentioned there is `dd/mm/yy` and time format is `HH:mm:ss`, here everything is working fine when the user selecting the date ..

When User selects the date I am getting date In expected format in my Action class. But When I redirect to same page after completing the action my date pickers text fields are being set by the wrong format like this `mm/dd/yyy` .. I want my date datepickers formats to be set to the date format I mentioned in my `datepicker` tag.

Becuase of this user is getting confused can any one tell me how to set the same format what the user has selected before the action even after the action completed

I m using `struts2 jquery plugin`

Comment: I think the date format for the plugin will be applied only to inputs and not on pre-populated values. You might look at formatting the date on server side or use JSTL date formatter.

Comment: @NikhilTalreja I am getting correct format in server side even If I consider formatting server side. .. And I am caching that Date as String in Action is it because of that ?

Comment: I don't think caching is an issue. What I meant was that when you are sending the date back to the front end, format it on the server side itself and send back. Better option is to use JSTL date formatter.

Comment: Thats What I mean When  I see the format Of date in my action is fine but it looks different in JSP Thats the problem.. To set the date format is actually in right format..

Comment: @NikhilTalreja I did some Cross Checking . that DataPicker is having Default Date Format It seems like `mm/dd/yyyy` So whatever the Format I set back to date picker after Action completion. Its Showing that Default Format.. So do I have any Chance That I can modify Date picker default format. Thanks

Comment: Try to use the value attribute and set the value directly

Comment: @NikhilTalreja I did that but no luck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is because `dd/mm/yy` is **not a valid format** according to `struts2 jquery`.

Valid format is `dd.mm.yy` or `dd-mm-yy`

Valid Formats according to this link are: [Click here](https://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/wiki/DatePickerTag#Datepicker_with_different_formats)

> dd.mm.yy
>   mm/dd/yy
>   DD, d MM yy
>   d M, yy
>   dd-mm-yy

They say

> `displayFormat` --> A pattern used for the visual display of the formatted date, e.g. yy-
>    mm-dd , dd.mm.yy

But pattern `dd/mm/yy` is not working. They also did not specified `/`(Slash) in `dd/mm/yy` **description of displayFormat**. They specified `.` (Dot) and `-` (Dash) only.

I have also tried with `dd//mm//yy` which is working!!!

But not working with `dd/mm/yy` :(

**Reason:**

datepicker can't parse a string value `dd/mm/yy`. It is treating `dd/mm/yy` as `mm/dd/yy`.

For some values it fails in which it treats maximum value between day and month as day when both of them are less than 12.

**For Example:**

> **Input:** 02/07/2014 09:30:41
>
> **displayFormat:** dd/mm/yy
>
> **Actual Day :** 2
>   **Actual Month :** 7
>   **Actual Time:** 09:30:41
>
> **Parsedday :** 7
>   **Parsedmonth :** 2
>   **Parsedtime :** : 00:00:00
>
> **Output:** 07/02/2014 00:00:00

This is an issue which is open and still not solved. **Struts2 Jquery Team** have **accepted** that this is an issue. The status is accepted of this issue.

Here is the issue link

[Issue 1057 in struts2-jquery: datepicker can't parse a string value with a time component](https://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/issues/detail?id=1057)

### **Solution**

I will suggest you to use

> displayFormat="dd-mm-yy"

to solve your problem or wait for the [issue 1057](https://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/issues/detail?id=1057) to get solved.

According to my research Following function needs to be debugged with alert(err);

Actual function that parses is

```
//#######################################################################################
// Splits datetime string into date ans time substrings.
// Throws exception when date can't be parsed
// If only date is present, time substring eill be ''
//#######################################################################################
var splitDateTime = function(dateFormat, dateTimeString, dateSettings)
{
    try {
            var date = $.datepicker._base_parseDate(dateFormat, dateTimeString, dateSettings);
    } catch (err) {
            if (err.indexOf(":") >= 0) {
                    // Hack!  The error message ends with a colon, a space, and
                    // the "extra" characters.  We rely on that instead of
                    // attempting to perfectly reproduce the parsing algorithm.
        var dateStringLength = dateTimeString.length-(err.length-err.indexOf(':')-2);
        var timeString = dateTimeString.substring(dateStringLength);

        return [dateTimeString.substring(0, dateStringLength), dateTimeString.substring(dateStringLength)];

            } else {
                    throw err;
            }
    }
    return [dateTimeString, ''];
 };
```

**Source Code Link:** Line 1447  [jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js](https://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/source/browse/trunk/struts2-jquery-plugin/src/main/resources/template/js/plugins/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js)

```
 //#######################################################################################
 // override parseDate() because UI 1.8.14 throws an error about "Extra characters"
 // An option in datapicker to ignore extra format characters would be nicer.
 //#######################################################################################
 $.datepicker._base_parseDate = $.datepicker.parseDate;
 $.datepicker.parseDate = function(format, value, settings) {
var splitRes = splitDateTime(format, value, settings);
    return $.datepicker._base_parseDate(format, splitRes[0], settings);
 };
```

**Source Code Link:** Line 1340  [jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js](https://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/source/browse/trunk/struts2-jquery-plugin/src/main/resources/template/js/plugins/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js)

Comment: @Parh Trivedi THank you so  much for detailed explanation.. IF `dd/mm/yy` is not corrrect format I even tried with `dd.mm.yy` but again its setting back to `mm.dd.yy` .. :(

Comment: `dd.mm.yy` is valid pattern and in my pc I have checked with it. It is working in my pc with `struts2-jquery-plugin-3.7.1.jar`. Try cleaning your project and run again.

Answer (score 0):

I think that by setting the value of the Datepicker using a Java Date (instead of String) you should be fine:

```
<sj:datepicker name="testDate" 
               value="%{testDateValue}"
               ...
 ></sj:datepicker>
```

and in the action class:

```
public Date getTestDateValue()
{
    try {
        return new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss").parse(getTestDate());
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Creating a `SimpleDateFormat` in a getter each time the object is accessed definitely isn't a good practice.

Comment: Of course not, was just shortest code to demonstrate how to get the datepicker to behave correctly.